# Php парсинг массива

Tags: php, массивы

Добрый день!
Помогите пожалуйста со следующим вопросом.
Дано IPv4 адреса и список подсетей к которым они должны принадлежать.
Задача сопоставить ип адреса с подсетями к которым они принадлежат. Все подсети /27.
Я перевел ип адреса и подсети через ip2long в значения без точки.
получилось 2 массива

```
    $pop
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  int(168430090)
  [1]=>
  int(179996486)
}

$net_range
array(4840) {
  [0]=>
  array(2) {
    ["host_min"]=>
    string(10) "1509562368"
    ["host_max"]=>
    string(10) "1509562399"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(2) {
    ["host_min"]=>
    string(9) "174424480"
    ["host_max"]=>
    string(9) "174424511"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(2) {
    ["host_min"]=>
    string(9) "174424512"
    ["host_max"]=>
    string(9) "174424543"
      }
```

Вот сам код

```
<?php
#translate ip to align ($pop)
$ip =file ('IP_LS_ID', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
foreach ($ip as $value) {
        $pop[]=ip2long($value);
}
#getting subnets /27
$link = mysql_connect('10.0.0.220', 'dhcp', '1234')
        or die ('connect error! '. mysql_error());
        echo "Connected \n";
mysql_select_db('dhcpdb') or die ('ne mogu v database!');
$query = mysql_query("select subnet from dhcpdb.sharenetwork where city=8 and netmask=inet_aton('255.255.255.224')");
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $nets[]=$row;
}
foreach ($nets as $net){
        $net_max=$net[subnet] + 31;
        $net_range[]=array('host_min'=>"$net[subnet]", 'host_max'=>"$net_max");
}
var_dump($net_range);
?>
```

После этого я встал в тупик и не могу понят как распарсить между собой эти 2 массива, можете указать как это будет проще и эффективней?
На выходе хочу получить сроку с IP subnet
и так для всех 20000 ип адресов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Думаю раз маски везде одинаковые, лучше запомнить факт наличия подсетей в ассоциативном массиве:

```
while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
        $nets[$row['subnet']]=1;
}
```

потом идем в цикле по массиву ip-адресов и делаем:

```
if( isset($nets[$ip & 0xFFFFFFE0]) ) {
   подсеть найдена, можно печатать то что хотели
}
```

Пользуемся тем фактом, что `IP & маска-подсети` дает нам как раз саму подсеть.

Comment: Блин, вот это я дурак. Можно же действительно башем посчитать подсеть для каждого ип через Ipcalc. это конечно не так круто как на пхп но на пхп видимо еще кишка тонка что то написать. Спасибо огромное!